# multiselect dropdown with checkboxes functionality

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Folks

We are creating the application and used the jquery as discussed in this [website](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

we are using multiple select dropdown with checkboxes. ( as in the screenshot attached)

The issue is

we cannot update the return result of the ajax call.

eg

if i select the date to and date from then the result between these two dates should be filtered and should be displayed in the multiple select dropdown with checkboxes.

Let me know if there is any other way to implement the same.( multi select dropdown along with the checkbox functionality).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
You want to use `$("select").multiselect('refresh');` 
//create new object with ajax data
    var opt = $('<option />', {
                value: "new value",
                text: "new text"
            });
    opt.appendTo(jqselect );
    jqselect.multiselect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the `chosen` (from [jquery-chosen](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen)).

In `chosen` you can specify a filter, where you can use `select` with `multi` or not.